# Chrome javascript console acts strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Running this code **alternately** shows `<div id="c"></div>` and *expandable* `HTMLDivElement` in Chrome javascript console.

```
$(function() {
    console.log( $("#c")[0] );
});

<div id="c"></div>
```

<s>If I run `alert()` instead of `console.log()`, it always returns [object HTMLDivElement].</s>

Not that it disturbes me much, but shouldn't this kind of output be somewhat constant if the input doesn't change ? So is it a some kind of bug in how Chrome console renders an object or what?

By the way, I couldn't reproduce the issue through jsfiddle. 
My Chrome is version 21.0.1180.89 and jQuery - version 1.6.4.

---

**EDIT:** Example: I refresh the page, console shows `<div id="c"></div>` . Then I refresh the page once again, the console now shows expandable `HTMLDivElement` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

console.log has the ability to show you the object.
alert shows strings, numbers, primitive types, you pass an object and alert will say that is an object. because the tostring() of object returns [object HTMLDivElement] in your case.

Comment: Indeed, but the question was why is console.log() showing different things alternately - i've edited the question, so it would be more clear. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: When I loop in JS I see this on my page `[object HTMLDivElement]` just literally as text... My loop appends as normal, but this 'string' is just printed as text in the top of the loop. Can't figure out where it comes from in inspector. In firefox it's `[object window]` in stead of `[object HTMLDivElement]` in chrome and safari

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome console the `$` is already a reference for `document.getElementById()`, so try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(function() {
    console.log( jQuery("#c")[0] );
});
```

This should solve the issue, giving a uniform output. And as others answered, the alert is just applying a toString() method (since alert function is expecting to output a string).

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript alert is showing you the toString() result of the object because it can not display anything other than strings. The console is able to give you an interactive representation of the object.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question to make it more clear